# Query to display records that were entered today in postgres (Epoch time)

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with columns as:

```
                                                       Table "public.myapp_table1"
   Column   |          Type          |                          Modifiers                           | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                | not null default nextval('myapp_database1_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 model_name | character varying(150) | not null                                                     | extended |              | 
 device_id  | character varying(150) | not null                                                     | extended |              | 
 data       | jsonb                  | not null                                                     | extended |              |
```

Inside json field data, there is 'timestamp' where time is stored in epoch format (refer https://www.epochconverter.com/ )

I want to display all rows entered today.

I'm trying to query: (Bit newish in querying json data)

```
select distinct(device_id) from myapp_table1 where (data->'timestamp')> 1570077000;
```

where 1570077000 is today's epoch time starting 10:00 AM.

Error that I'm getting is:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb > integer
LINE 1: ...ce_id) from myapp_table1 where (data->'timestamp')> 15700770...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Not sure how to manage that '>' sign. Didn't get the hold of docs yet.

How to tackle this?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Putting parentheses around a column won't change that at all. `distinct (a)` is the same as `distinct a` and `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `->>` to get the JSON value as text, instead of `->`, which returns a json object. Also, it is probably needed to cast the text value to an (big) integer.

Consider:

```
where (data->>'timestamp')::bigint > 1570077000
```

Reference: [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: getting an error as:  value "1569409725248" is out of range for type integer
worked with 'bigint'. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AjayBhagchandani: welcome, and thanks for the fix, I added it to my answer.